# Is there a way to use a serial port at 2-3 mbps?

Tags: c#, serial-port

I need to stream serial data to and from a C# Windows PC application at 2-3 mbps. C# winforms doesn't seem very happy with it.

```
openFileDialog.Filter =
    @"Image Files(*.bmp;*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.gif)|*.bmp;*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.gif|All files (*.*)|*.*";
if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.OK) return;
var image = Image.FromFile(openFileDialog.FileName);
serialPort1.Open();
// Now send the image at 2-3 mbps
...
```

BaudRate = 115200 works. BaudRate = 230400 causes System.IO.IOException.

[image]

Comment: what does winforms have to do with that? Secondly, what does 'it' do when you say it seems not very happy? Also, the code shows nothing that has to do with serial communications. (There is an undeclared variable whose name suggests that it does, however, we don't know anything about that). How is this not 'show me the codez'?

Comment: I'm using the winforms serial port. Baud rate at 9600 is fine, but high values cause exception. I'll see how high it goes.

Comment: @JackN please edit your orginal question to include the setup and setting of the baud rate. Also please post the full text of the exception.

Comment: Also please include the hardware you are using, is it the RS232 port on the motherboard or is it something else?

Comment: Digi makes "AccelePort" serial cards with RISC controls that top out at 921.6 Kbps of data throughput.  I don't think you are going to find a serial card that you can push to 2-3MBS...

Comment: @Scrappydog: A USB-to-serial convertor might do too. IIRC the FT232 (like on the older Arduino) supports up to 921.6 Kbps.

Comment: @leppie: The FT232 family supports 2.0 and 3.0 Mbaud.  See my comment on Daniel's answer.  Usually you want RS422 (differential pair) for those kinds of speeds, but over a short distance RS-232 can do it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Open up device manager and expand out "ports".

[image]

double click on COM1 and go to the "Port Settings" tab

[image]

Under "Bits per second" lists values you can enter in the proprieties field for your com port. If you want higher than what your hardware allows you need other hardware or use something other than a serial port to transfer between the two devices.

If you would post in the comments what is the other device you are connecting to, we may be able to suggest a better way.

Comment: The HW limitation is on the serial port HW built into the PC (115200 max). I installed the drivers for a USB-2COM-PRO and found I set the rate to 3mbps without issue on the appropriate COM port (COM5). Thanks a million.

Answer (score 5):

This post is 4 years old, so for those stumbling upon it:

1st, the serial port hardware needs to support the datarate. 2nd, the driver needs to let you choose the desired baudrate. Some drivers or chips may require tweaking to let you select non-standard (or higher than 115200) baudrates. The max baudrate of a few USB to serial chips I've come across:

- **Silicon Labs CP2102 & CP2109**: 921.6 kbps
- **FTDI FT232R**: 3 Mbps
- **Prolific PL-2303HX & PL-2303HXD**: 12Mbps

I'm currently using the FT232R @ 1Mbps

Regarding the use of C# and .NET: .NET seems to suck at serial ports. See http://www.sparxeng.com/blog/software/must-use-net-system-io-ports-serialport (which references this thread and is how I got here).

A coworker made a c# .NET program for me to communicate at 1Mbps using the FT232R with .NET 3.5. It worked on his PC and a Notebook, but would instead be stuck at 9600bps on my PC. Tried several things including driver uninstalling, rebooting, cold start and manual driver installation to no avail. He then recompiled it for .NET 4 and voilá, it worked. The funny thing is right after that he handed me a minor modification but mistakingly compiled it for .NET 3.5, but it worked.

Answer (score 4):

If your hardware supports those speeds, then Windows does as well.  The .NET SerialPort class may or may not allow you to set the baud rate that high, if not then try calling [`SetCommState`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363436.aspx).

Comment: it calls `GetCommProperties` internally.

Comment: @Daniel: And what does it do when it sees `BAUD_USER`?

Comment: `baudRate > this.commProp.dwMaxBaud`

Comment: @Daniel: Well, that surely is broken, since [the `dwMaxBaud` field in `COMMPROP` is a bit flag, not a baud rate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363189.aspx).  Using p/invoke to call `SetCommState` and bypass the broken `SerialPort` class seems like a reasonable workaround, IMO.

Comment: No, it isn't its just looks that way. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363189(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: those are hex values in there, hence its not a bitflag.

Comment: @Daniel: Every one of those values corresponds to a single bit.  I know how hexadecimal works.  `dwSettableBaud` is a bitmask (many bits set).  `dwMaxBaud` is a one-hot encoding, only one bit is allowed to be set.  You can't compare this bitflag encoding to a numeric baud rate.

Comment: Very funny comment by Daniel A White above... "those are hex values in there, hence its not a bitflag." Having trouble understanding why he didn't delete that comment; does he still think bitfields can't be expressed as hex values??? I suppose he probably thinks 0x41 can't possibly be the letter "A"; duh, it's a hex value!

Answer (score 2):

No. That is a limitation of the hardware. forom looking at the internals, it looks like windows has a max.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363189(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: How can you say that when he hasn't said which hardware he's using?

Comment: i've never seen one that high.

Answer (score 2):

I have used BlueTooth serial ports that ran at 1Mbps, and it seemed like it didn't care what speed was set.

Comment: which part number?

Comment: Bluetooth serial is a virtualised UART, the baud rate will be ignored.  The only time it would be used would be to set the baud rate of the UART in a Bluetooth-UART bridge.  Same with USB-Serial.

Answer (score -1):

Serial ports generally supports speeds up to 115200 bps, or just over 14 KBps. Some devices support higher baud rates, but you're a long way from 2-3 mbps.

Is there a particular reason you're choosing to use a serial port? While still used, it's widely deprecated in favor of more modern approaches. If you're transferring between processes on one machine, a named pipe or just using the filesystem might be better. If you're transferring between two computers, consider using TCP/IP networking.

This link on MSDN talks about the different transports that WCF recommends and supports, and might be a good place to start looking. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733769.aspx

Comment: I asked the same questions when tasked with this. I much prefer TCP/IP or UDP for this kind of stuff. But these are customer requirements for existing installations using RS485.

Comment: Unfortunately (or perhaps fortunately) part of being a good software engineer is knowing when to push back. Clients often ask for the way-out-there or the impossible, and this often manifests as impossible performance requirements. If a client asks to be able to back up a 5TB server remotely in under ten minutes, there's nothing to do but explain to them the technical limitations and then try to figure out how I _can_ help them solve their problems.

Comment: But impossible tasks are so much fun.